# How to retain the timestamp format when extracting from a dataframe into a string in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have the following dataframe in PySpark (Databricks). How can I extract the exact literal timestamp as displayed in the dataframe into a string?. At the moment, using the code below, I  get: **"2022-02-25 06:32:29"** instead of **"2022-02-25T06:32:29.000+0000"**. some conversion is happening that strips of the milliseonds part including the 'T'. I want to retain the literal string as it appears on the dataframe?

**code**:

```
table = [x["ts"] for x in ts.rdd.collect()]
for row in table:
    print(row)
```

[image: Dataframe]

Answer (score 0):

timestamps & dates under the hood aren't the strings, but have types like int & long, and it's up to the client program to convert these data into a visual representation. You can use the [date_format](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.date_format.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_format) function to explicitly convert timestamp or date into a string if you want to have uniform data representation...